# Python Error importing Curses - not sure why

Tags: python, curses

So I do have curses installed Ive checked it with dpkg.
Now when I try to import it, this happens

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan 13 2013, 11:20:46)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import curses
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "curses.py", line 3, in <module>
    myscreen = curses.initscr()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'initscr'
```

I have no idea why it happens - I first tried to run this:

```
import curses

myscreen = curses.initscr()
myscreen.border(0)
myscreen.addstr(12, 25, "Python curses in action!")
myscreen.refresh()
myscreen.getch()

curses.endwin()
```

Since I tried it, this happens. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Do you have a file of your own called `curses.py` in your working directory or on your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "curses.py", line 3, in <module>
```

It seems you named your own file curses.py, 
Python looks in the current directory first so you cannot have the same name as a library.

Comment: my god .. someone please hit me with a stick! Yes thats indeed it.

Comment: @Jrc: WHACK!  Now don't do it again. :-)  (But to be fair, we've all been there.)

Comment: Its a sign to answer the call of my bed! Thanks everyone and sorry for the silly mistake!